# Doesn't show data correctly

Tags: graph, amcharts

I have prepared linear graph and some data [here](https://codepen.io/cherioss/pen/xpNgrJ?editors=0010).

As you can see, when you try display details of samples in the middle, graph show detail of another one. As the date format I am using Unix timestamp.

Next problem is rectangle below which should show sample's date, instead of it show day, month, and some number. I require date format like `YYYY/MM/DD - mm:ss`.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",
        "marginRight": 80,
        "autoMarginOffset": 20,
        "marginTop": 7,
        "dataDateFormat": "YYYY/MM/DD JJ:NN:QQQ",
        "dataProvider": chartData,
        "valueAxes": [{
            "axisAlpha": 0.2,
            "dashLength": 1,
            "position": "left",
        }],
        "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
        "graphs": [{
            "id": "g1",
            "balloonText": "BallonText",
            "bullet": "round",
            "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
            "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "hideBulletsCount": 50,
            "title": "red line",
            "valueField": "yCoordinate",
            "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
            "balloon":{
                "drop":true
            }
        }],
        "chartScrollbar": {
            "autoGridCount": true,
            "graph": "g1",
            "scrollbarHeight": 40
        },
        "chartCursor": {
            "limitToGraph":"g1"
        },
        "categoryField": "xCoordinate",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "parseDates": true,
            "axisColor": "#DADADA",
            "dashLength": 1,
            "minorGridEnabled": true
        },
        "export": {
            "enabled": true
        },
    } );
```

Comment: when I delete 
   ` "chartCursor": {
                "limitToGraph":"g1"
     }, `
It show detail of each sample, but it is not pretty, it isn't solve my problem :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

1) Your date-based data must be sorted in ascending, per the [`parseDates` documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates) documentation. Your dates are out of order, which will cause chart behavior issues like what you're seeing.

2) You have to set your category axis [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) to match the smallest period between each of your dates in your data. It looks like seconds (`"ss"`) are appropriate.

As for formatting the chart cursor, you can set [`categoryBalloonDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#categoryBalloonDateFormat) to the desired format. In this case `"YYYY/MM/DD - NN:SS"` is what you want. Refer to the [formatting dates documentation](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/) if you need to use different formats.

Also note that [`dataDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat) is not necessary if you're using millisecond timestamps. `dataDateFormat` is only used to parse your date data if they are strings.

Updated code below:

```js
var chartData = [
  {
    xCoordinate: 1511509736056,
    yCoordinate: 1
  },
  {
    xCoordinate: 1511509955035,
    yCoordinate: 1
  },
  {
    xCoordinate: 1511510013033,
    yCoordinate: 1
  },
  {
    xCoordinate: 1511510152052,
    yCoordinate: 1
  },
  {
    xCoordinate: 1511510436036,
    yCoordinate: 1
  },
  {
    xCoordinate: 1511510664024,
    yCoordinate: 1
  }
];

//sort dates into ascending order
chartData.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
  return lhs.xCoordinate - rhs.xCoordinate;
});

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  type: "serial",
  theme: "light",
  marginRight: 80,
  autoMarginOffset: 20,
  marginTop: 7,
  dataProvider: chartData,
  valueAxes: [
    {
      axisAlpha: 0.2,
      dashLength: 1,
      position: "left"
    }
  ],
  mouseWheelZoomEnabled: true,
  graphs: [
    {
      id: "g1",
      balloonText: "BallonText",
      bullet: "round",
      bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
      bulletColor: "#FFFFFF",
      hideBulletsCount: 50,
      title: "red line",
      valueField: "yCoordinate",
      useLineColorForBulletBorder: true,
      balloon: {
        drop: true
      }
    }
  ],
  chartScrollbar: {
    autoGridCount: true,
    graph: "g1",
    scrollbarHeight: 40
  },
  chartCursor: {
    limitToGraph: "g1",
    categoryBalloonDateFormat: "YYYY/MM/DD - NN:SS" //change date format in cursor
  },
  categoryField: "xCoordinate",
  categoryAxis: {
    parseDates: true,
    axisColor: "#DADADA",
    dashLength: 1,
    minPeriod: "ss", //update min period to match the smallest intervals in your data.
    minorGridEnabled: true
  },
  export: {
    enabled: true
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```